# Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) Drivers for Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, intel-graphics

I have a game (supertuxkart) that says I need to update my video drivers and it uses opengl 3.1. The driver has to be 64bit because I have a 64bit system.

If there are any drivers, please list them and also show the link

Output of `glxinfo | more`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10185465/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no drivers under Linux: There is something called "modules" in the Linux kernel and some people call them "drivers" because that's what Microsoft calls them...  ;-)

That being said, the modules are built into the kernel and are already installed. To activate opengl, do:

```
 sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

and then you can do a:

```
 glxinfo | more
```

And I'm sorry to say, but the [SuperTuxCart System Requirements](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/FAQ#Hardware_requirements) are incompatible with your computer...  On the other hand: [Trophy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=trophy) should still work!

Comment: I pretty sure that I can't play it because on freegamedev(where I also asked) someone said the 945G uses drivers older than than the 965 chipset and they also said that it only supports 1.4 openGL

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10185465/

Comment: Aha!  Finally!  (please delete all tour other comments, I will do the same as we're reaching the maximum)

Comment: So that "someone" was talking out of their ....  They were dead wrong!  :(

Comment: Well so much for this! I got a new computer with a amd saphire hd7770 on 16.04, but gotta do something about that new download size for the new supertuxkart.